# Что такое i в цикле for

Tags: c#

Не могу до конца понять, что такое i в цикле for. Понятно, что обычная переменная, можно другими символами имя ей задать. Понимаю, что она нужна для счёта, но путаюсь. Например:
Мне нужно вывести список list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 15; i ++)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                var tp = int.TryParse(input, out int result);
                if (tp == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It`s not int");
                }

                list.Add(result);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
                
        
    }
}
```

Не понимаю, почему выводятся элементы списка. Мне кажется, написано: пока количество выведенных на экран элементов списка меньше, чем количество всех элементов, выводить на экран количество остальных элементов поочерёдно.
А вот зачем в `Console.WriteLine` написано, чтобы выводился i этого списка, я не понимаю. Ну, как бы, это тяжело объяснить. Что такое i этот? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: я не понял вопроса. Вы не знаете, как работает for? Или вы не знаете что такое индексатор для списка?

Comment: Что такое индексатор, скорее

Comment: [Индексаторы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.10.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам непонятна строка Console.WriteLine(list[i]); Мы выводим не элемент i, а итый элемент списка list. Чтобы это понять, представьте на месте i любое число, например, Console.WriteLine(list[1]); Эта запись будет означать: "вывести первый элемент списка"

Comment: @Lirika, честно сказать, С# немного не мой профиль, но если я правильно понял ваш код, то в вашем последнем цикле for (for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)), list.Count и есть количество всех ваших элементов списка, так что просто выводите его через writeLine. Может, вы хотели вывести все элементы в одной строке, а не их количество?

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, i у вас используется в двух местах, но видимо как оно используется в первом цикле вам понятно. Если нет, вкратце - в первом цикле for просто 15 раз запрашивает ввод данных из консоли. В этом цикле переменная i не более чем итератор, который отсчитывает какое по счету число вы вводите.

Кстати, что любопытно, проверка у вас на int работает, но если не int, то лишь информирует, и все равно пытается добавлять в список введенное значение. Наверное так и было задумано....

Во вторых, во втором цикле Вы верно понимает, что это перебор элементов списка list. И тогда i при каждой итерации цикла указывает на i-й элемент из списка list. Получается, что вы просто по порядку перебираете с первого по последний элементы в списке и выводите их на экран. list[i] - это значение, которое хранится в списке на позиции i. В данном случае i уже можно считать индексом значения (применимо к списку list). Само значение i на экран у вас в коде нигде не выводится при этом. Только значение из списка list.

Как уже вам в комментариях подсказали, можете вместо i просто написать цифру.
К примеру list[0] - первый элемент списка, list[10] - одинадцатый и так далее. Чтобы иметь возможность вводить и выводить произвольное количество значений, вставили такой вот цикл, вместо вывода конкретных индексов, их перебирают в цикле. И i во втором цикле никак не относится к i в первом цикле.

Answer (score -1):

Переменная list это указатель на ячейку оперативной памяти, тоесть на первый элемент массива, list[0] это первый элемент т.к. смещение равно 0. list[1] смещает указатель на 1 элемент соответственно это уже указатель на 2й элемент массива. В вашем цикле переменная i меняет свое значение от 0 до 14 (i<15) получается что вы получаете первое значение, а потом 14 раз смещает указатель в памяти и получаете ещё 14 значений одно за другим. Таким образом имея одну переменную list вы можете получить 15 разных значений памяти а не одно как с обычной переменной.